# What is strafe jumping?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier, tf2-demoman

I've seen people rocket and sticky jump, but make incredible turns in the air.  In Team Fortress 2, for example, I've seen people on 2Fort jump out of one side of the battlements, do a 180, and land in the other side.  Is this an example of strafe jumping? How is it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is strafe jumping.

If you hold down one of the strafe keys, and *at the same time* move your mouse *in the same direction*, you will move through the air in that direction.

You should be able to find some "surf" maps to help train your strafe jumping.

---

**Edit:**

I forgot that there are also "klimberz" maps to train on.  You can search Google for "[KZ Maps](http://www.google.com/search?q=KZ%20Maps)". Since CS:S uses the same physics engine, you may be able to train your strafe jumping there.

Comment: What is the effect of holding down the forward key while strafe jumping?

Comment: I think that it loses the effect.  I'm not 100% on that, tho.

Comment: There's a big difference between surf/kz maps on TF2 and CS:S. It's not the same engine. CS:S uses a very outdated version of the Source engine.

Comment: @Arda:  Not as big of a difference as, say, TF2 and Quake.  The point is that the controls "feel" the same, even if the exact distances and gravity are different.

Comment: I believe that crouching while you are in the air also aids your turning circle. But i could be wrong on that...

Comment: @Arda Xi: CS:S was updated to use the TF2 engine a few months back.